# Segfault on dynamically allocated integer array malloced in a different function

Tags: c, dynamic, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void a(int** parr) {
    *parr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
}

void b(int** parr) {
  *parr[0] = 100;
  *parr[1] = 200;
}

int main(void) {
  int* parr;
  a(&parr);
  parr[0] = 50;
  parr[1] = 75;
  b(&parr);
  printf("%d %d\n", parr[0], parr[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

For some reason, this segfaults on `*parr[1] = 200` and I can't figure out why. I'm passing in an integer pointer to the array into `b()`, and `*parr[0] = 100` works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

The `[]` operator has higher precedence than the dereference `*` operator. So those two lines of code need to engage the services of parenthesis to get the desired order of operations:

```
(*parr)[0] = 100;
(*parr)[1] = 200;
```

Also, there is really no reason for the `b` function to take a double pointer as it does not change the original `parr` pointer (compared to `a` function which does). So the code could be more simply and less error pronely written as:

```
void b(int* parr) {
  parr[0] = 100;
  parr[1] = 200;
}
```

And called with:

```
b(parr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, that fixed it. Function `b` took a double pointer because I was doing some realloc with it, forgot to change it when making this post.